# How many of APNS notifications don't get deliverd?

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications

So, I know that APNS doesn't guarantee push notifications delivery. We are considering implementing "guaranteed delivery" of push notifications (we could resend those notifications that haven't been read by the user, for example). I'm not sure if it's worth it though.

Can you please tell me
- are there any stats on how many notifications get delivered, and how many don't get delivered?
- under what circumstances notifications don't get delivered?

Comment: The most common circumstance would be when the user is offline.  If two notifications are sent when the user is offline then the first is lost.

Comment: I don't think so if there is any way to accurately know as of now that a notification could not be delivered to client. APNS Server responds back with 200 OK most of the times even when notification is yet to be delivered or even dropped in case of multiple notifications coalesced.